# Get the right this-context in an overwritten function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

I have the following problem:

I'm trying to overwrite a function to apply it then with angular (`$scope.$apply()`), but my `this`-context doesn't seem to be the right one.

The original function (in another file) looks like the following:

```
Anno.prototype.switchTo = function(otherAnno) {
    if (otherAnno != null) {
        this.hideAnno();
        return otherAnno.show();
    } else {
        console.warn("Can't switchTo a null object. Hiding instead.");
        return this.hide();
    }
};
```

And then in another file I "overwrite" it like the following:

```
var switchToFunction = AnnoModule.Anno.prototype.switchTo;
AnnoModule.Anno.prototype.switchTo = function(otherAnno) {
    switchToFunction(otherAnno);
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

So actually I save the original function, then redefine the original function to call the original one and then apply the scope.

Now comes the problem: As you can see, the function uses `this.hideAnno()` in it, but in my redefined function, the context is another one, that's why chrome is throwing an error saying "this.hideAnno() is not a function". But now I'm not sure how I can get the right context. I tried to understand [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/), but I find JavaScript is so confusing that I really don't get it.

Can somebody help me understand that JavaScript confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is called as a method in js, the `this` inside of it refers to the object the method belongs to.

On the other hand, when a function is called on its own, `this` inside of it refers to the global object or `undefined` in strict mode.

You are extracting (and then calling) a function defined as a method into a standalone function, that's why `this` doesn't do what you expect it to.

What you need in this case is to [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) your `switchToFunction`, setting the value of `this` to what you need. In other words you set the `this` of the old method to be the `this` of the new method you created:

```
var switchToFunction = AnnoModule.Anno.prototype.switchTo;
AnnoModule.Anno.prototype.switchTo = function(otherAnno, that) {
    switchToFunction.call(this, otherAnno); // sets `this` of the old method to be this of the new method you created
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Wouldn't have expected to be that easy... I even already tried using the `call` method on the same position as you thit, but I didn't write `this` as first parameter.

Comment: Glad to help :). Yes, the only purpose of `call` or `apply` is to set the value of `this` when calling a function, not much else

Answer (score 1):

To understand the problem, I think first we should understand how `this` keyword works and how it can be tweaked.

> In JavaScript the `this` object inside of any function will be the **object** on which the **method** is invoked.

Consider these following example,

```
var obj1 = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

function bar() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Now when the methods are invoked we get output like below,

```
obj1.foo();     // obj1
bar();          // window
```

> Because `foo` method is invoked on `obj1`, so `this` inside of `foo` method became `obj1`. Similarly `this` inside `bar` method will be `window` object.

Now, what if I want to invoke the `bar` method with `obj1` as `this` inside the function. For this JavaScript provides `call, apply and bind` methods to change the `this` of function dynamically. Let us see how we can achieve this using `call` method.

```
bar.call(obj1);         // obj1
```

Similarly,

```
obj1.foo.call(window);          // window
```

`call` method takes an `thisArg` object as argument which will be `this` inside the `bar` function. And if `bar` function also expects arguments that also can be passed through `call` method following `thisArg`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for information about `call`.

So the solution for your problem will be,

```
var switchToFunction = AnnoModule.Anno.prototype.switchTo;
AnnoModule.Anno.prototype.switchTo = function(otherAnno) {
    switchToFunction.call(this, otherAnno);
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

Hope this makes it clear for you to understand the problem.